# How can I determine if this method is threadsafe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, locking

```
private void PerformValuations(DateTime testDate, RegressionEffectivenessTest.RegressionDateWithValues date)
        {
            var valueDate = new LegacyWCFRateTimeStamp { Type = RateTimeStampType.EndOfDay, TimeStamp = date.ValueDate };
            var curveDate = new LegacyWCFRateTimeStamp { Type = RateTimeStampType.EndOfDay, TimeStamp = date.CurveDate };
            var shiftDate = new LegacyWCFRateTimeStamp { Type = RateTimeStampType.EndOfDay, TimeStamp = date.ShiftDate };
            if (date.NeedHedgeValues)
            {
                date.HedgeCleanPrice = 0M;
                date.HedgeCleanIntrinsicValue = 0M;
                foreach (var tran in _hedgeTranQuoteIds)
                {
                    var tranquoteId = tran.TranQuoteId;
                    CheckAndLoadTrade(testDate, valueDate, shiftDate, curveDate, tran, tranquoteId);
                    var result = ValueTrade(tranquoteId);

                    var rtnVal = !result.Succeeded
                                     ? HandleFailure(tranquoteId, shiftDate, curveDate, result, valueDate)
                                     : CreateAccountingValuation(valueDate, result);
                    date.HedgeCleanIntrinsicValue += rtnVal.IntrinsicValue - rtnVal.AccruedInterest.GetValueOrDefault(0);
                    date.HedgeCleanPrice += rtnVal.CleanPrice;
                }
            }
```

So I'm trying to run a `Parallel.ForEach` on this method. There were a couple of things that I was worried about. The first one is within the `CheckAndLoadTrade` method, it accesses a `private Dictionary` of the class to possibly add an item to it if it isn't there, and then the `ValueTrade` method gets an item from this dictionary.

If I parallel this out, am I going to run into any thread safety issues with the dictionary being accessed? Or possibly anything else I didn't notice? All other method calls use variables defined in their own scope, it's really just this one `Dictionary` that I am worried about. Should I throw a `lock` before and after the actual dictionary access happens?

Comment: Are the `date` values shared between loops? Because `+=` operations (that occur on its `HedgeCleanIntrinsicValue` and `HedgeCleanPrice`) are not thread-safe. Perhaps you should post your `CheckAndLoadTrade` method. Anything happen in `CreateAccountingValuation` or `ValueTrade` that should be noted?

Comment: How do you want this access to work? if you iterate over a shared `_hedgeTranQuoteIds` (whether it is defined as a concurrent list or NOT) you will potentially get duplicate `tran` values handled by multple threads. Is this what you want? Does any method remove the object retrieved by `tran` from the list so it doesn't re-retrieve? If retrieving the same value is ok, then yes, just make the CheckAndLoad method and the ValueTrade methods lock the dictionary  on entry. However, depending on your code, you *may* be able to get away with only using a concurrent dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What part are you trying to parallelize?  The foreach loop?

If you can, use a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx). within `CheckAndLoadTrade`.  Another concern is what code runs when the trade is not in the dictionary.  Is the "loadtrade" code thread-safe?

Comment: The answer to your first question: yes. And when the trade is not in the dictionary, the `LoadTrade` method runs and yes it is thread safe minus the fact that it's accessing the same dictionary. Everything it does minus that is a call to a web service and handles its own variables.

Comment: then, if you can change the method to use a ConcurrentDictionary that will likely be the most performant approach.